# Case while working with a number of version format

Tags: javascript, typescript

When i get a number in the format of version Example "1.0.0.0".If i need to increment to the next version of the number and that would result in "1.0.0.1"

using the below code of regex
will get the perfect result as "1.0.0.1"- increment of version

```js
let version = "1.0.0.0";
let nextVersion = version.replace(/.$/, parseInt(version[version.length - 1], 10) + 1);

console.log(nextVersion)
```

But, if I get a number as "1" not in a format of version but I would expect the same result as above to be "1.0.0.1".How would I deal with a number in this case?
if a number is "22" I would expect it to be "22.0.0.1"

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. If your `version=22.0.0.0` it outputs `22.0.0.1`, which is correct, right?

Comment: @PratikGandhi if version = "22" it should output as 22.0.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split and fill the version array and then add one to the last item.

```js
function next(version) {
    var items = version.split('.').map(Number);
        
    while (items.length < 4) items.push(0);
    items[3]++;
    
    return items.join('.');
}

console.log(next("1.0.0.0"));
console.log(next("1"));
console.log(next("22"));
```

Comment: I feel like the index `3` used in `items[3]++` should be a variable, with a default value of 3. So the same function can be used to increment the other values as well.

Comment: maybe, but op asked for a fixed position for incrementing a value.

Comment: @nickzoum I had the same idea  - perhaps my code is what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I made a version where you pass the position you want to increment.

If the position does not exist, it is created, if position is not passed it is 3

```js
const nextVersion = (ver, pos=3) => {
  let [main,...rest] = ver.split(".")
  rest = Array.isArray(rest) && rest.length > 0 ? rest : Array(pos).fill(0,0,pos);
  if (rest.length<pos) rest.push(0); // make sure it is long enough
  +rest[pos-1]++; // interestingly enough the + was not needed here
  return `${main}.${rest.join(".")}`; // or use rest.unshift(main)
}

console.log(nextVersion("22",3))
console.log(nextVersion("1.0.0.1",3))
console.log(nextVersion("22",1))
console.log(nextVersion("22.1",1))
console.log(nextVersion("22.1",2))
console.log(nextVersion("1.0.0.1",1))
console.log(nextVersion("22")); // no parameters
```